# 2GP: How to set Managed Package Publisher Name

Tags: managed-package, second-generation-packaging

How do I set an App's Publisher Name?

Looking at the [Project Configuration File for Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm) I cannot see anywhere in the `sfdx-project.json` where it could be added.

Using 1GP it was set in the packaging org... but these don't exist in 2GP.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the [company Name](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338722&type=1&mode=1) in your DevHub org that is used for App publisher name.

Navigate to the `Set up > Company Profile > Company Information` in your DevHub and next package you generate will have this as the Publisher Name.

Comment: Our company information is set correctly in our production org, which is also out `Dev Hub` but the `Publisher` is still empty.

Comment: @Robs Can you try creating a new package and see if that picks up. Try creating a new 2GP package altogether. If this works, then raise a support ticket so someone can help you change this for your current package from the backend.

Comment: I've created 8 beta versions, and it's never picked it up. My scratch org isn't appearing in my `Envrionment Hub`, would that be an issue?

Comment: Are you creating a package version or package? Note it has to be a package and not version

Comment: Ah! I am creating a `version`, but the company name information was already set when I created the `package`

Comment: I suggest you raise a case! The app publisher name is picked from the company name of your Dev Hub org

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this? We have the same problem, and the company information was filled out from the very beginning.

Comment: @lightxx must be a bug! Please log a support ticket.

Comment: @lightxx it has updated for me after some time. I believe that the answer is correct. Just need to refresh browser cache or wait a while.